# Change ViewPager fragment with Navigation item click

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragmenttransaction

I have `ViewPager` to hold fragments. I want to change the `fragments` with `Navigation` item click as all the `fragments` name will be in Nav bar.

`app_bar_main.xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ml.sudarshan.bangladesh.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bangladesh_m"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

My Java codes.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the 10
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

I could not find the way to replace fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside navigation view

viewPager.setCurrentItem(THE_POSITION)

Nav listener

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() { @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) { menuItem.setChecked(true); mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers(); 
viewPager.setCurrentItem(THE_POSITION)
return true; } });
```